# jquery wait for .animate then go to anchor location

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm using jquery animate to slide a div off the page, this works fine but i would like to change the animate to:

1. only happen once(because if somebody double clicks it, the div comes back), and
2. wait for animation to finish before the href is followed.

This is the code that performs the div slide:

```
$(".choose").click(function(event) {
    var $contentDiv = $("#content");

    $contentDiv.stop().animate({
        marginLeft: parseInt($contentDiv.css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ?
        $contentDiv.outerWidth() : 0
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default click action, and then do a manual redirect by setting `location.href` after the animation using a callback...

```
$(".choose").click(function(event) {
    var $contentDiv = $("#content");
    var redir = $(this).attr("href");

    $contentDiv.stop().animate({
        marginLeft: parseInt($contentDiv.css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ?
        $contentDiv.outerWidth() : 0
    }, function() { location.href = redir; });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: That's what i wanted, i'd been beating around the bush with event.prenetDefault but it didnt work the way i did it lol. Thank You